# Unity- how to have transparent glowing material/screens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, glow

Ok I have tried unity’s glowing shaders but have not had success and am new to shaders in general- I need to achieve this effect:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: You might ask on the Unity forums since they specialize on Unity there.

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/search?q=hologram&q=shader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial using Shader Graph
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGGB5LFEejg

And here is a plugin
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yEH8XYnqZY

Answer (score 0):

This is a playlist with some information about how to use Shader Graph.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX2vGYjWbI0RyhAsNJg4sLLKgCZsRSim2

In that playlist you will find this video:

https://youtu.be/qTYOWRWuBQg

Which shows how to make a glow shader like the one in the picture below.

[image: Glow Shader]